# Build cordova project using xcodebuild command

Tags: cordova, jenkins, xcodebuild

I m working on custom plugin for `Jenkins` to build iOS project using command line. 
The native project able to build using `xcodebuild` command where as the hybrid (`cordova`) project when I build getting build failure.

**Shell script:**

```
xcodebuild -project app.xcodeproj -alltargets
```

The error I m getting is

```
app/Classes/AppDelegate.h:30:9: fatal error: 
      'Cordova/CDVViewController.h' file not found
#import <Cordova/CDVViewController.h>
```

Same for other class files as well.

The folder structure is as below.

```
App
- CordovaLib  
   -CordovaLib.xcodeproj
- Cordova
   -build 
   -run
- App.xcodeproj
```

Help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-scheme` instead of `-target` or `-alltargets`:

```
xcodebuild \
    -scheme ${projectname} \
    -project ${projectname}.xcodeproj \
    -configuration Release \
    -sdk iphoneos \
    build \
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="${CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY}" \
    PROVISIONING_PROFILE="${PROVISIONING_PROFILE}" \
    OBJROOT=${AngejiaBuildPath} \
    SYMROOT=${AngejiaBuildPath}
```

Answer (score 2):

`xcodebuild -scheme myProject -configuration "config" -project app.xcodeproj -alltargets` could do the trick... i find that not providing the schema or configuration causes problems with xcodebuild...